# Set workdir/pwd of go build

Tags: go

Is it possible to set the workdir to a different path?

For example, I want to run `go build` from the root path, but my source code is under a different directory, and I do not want to `cd` to it.

npm, for example, has the `--prefix`, which serves for this purpose.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Include an example of your project setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

```
go build -o [output file path/name] [source code file path/name]
```

For example, if your source code file is located in `projectdir/code/src/` and want to build and save output to `projectdir/code/out`, do following:

```
$ go build -o projectdir/code/out/main projectdir/code/src/main.go
```

As per `go build` documentation:

> If the named output is an existing directory or ends with a slash or
> backslash, then any resulting executables will be written to that
> directory.

So our above build command can be rewritten like this:

```
go build -o projectdir/code/out/ projectdir/code/src/main.go
```

and it will generate executable named `main` in `projectdir/code/out/` directory.

For more details, run `go help build`

Comment: Note that you solution doesn't change the working directory as the OP requested.

Comment: Totally agreed. go build -o is not exactly equal to as --prefix in npm context. But the OP's mentioned use case can be achieved using this flag. Also OP accepted the answer without any follow up, as this is the closest matching solution.

Answer (score -3):

No, this is not possible with 1.19. Just cd into it.

Go 1.20 (yet unreleased) brings the -C flag which might be what you want.